# What is the velocity on perimeter of a wheel when it is hit by hand tangentially to increase speed?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

This is a homework problem in Newtonian mechanics. The problem statement is

> A circular wheel (whose radius is $R$ and moment of inertia is $I$) is hit by a
> hand of mass $m$ repeatedly with a velocity of $v$ (in rest reference
> frame) tangentially on its circumference so that it speeds up in the
> direction of rotation. It is hit in such a way that the hand loses all of
> it's momentum after impact wrt. the reference frame of the point of
> impact.
>
> The hand is moving along with the elbow, neglecting rotation of forearm.
> Considering the hand to be a point mass, what is the velocity of the
> perimeter of the wheel after n hits? [Hint: Solve the recurrence
> relation]

The whole situation sounds so complicated that I don't know even where to start or how to approach such a problem. Can anyone say how to approach this? Also, does anyone here know the original source (the book where it originated first) of this seemingly hard problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, each time the hand hits the wheel its speed in the lab frame is reduced from $v$ to $v_{i}$, where I'll call $v_{i}$ the speed of the wheel in the lab frame after $i$ hits.

So on the $(i+1)^{th}$ hit, the change in momentum of the hand is $\Delta p = m(v_{i}-v)$. The average force applied to the **wheel** assuming the collision takes place over an interval of time $\Delta t$ then equals $F=\frac{m(v-v_{i})}{\Delta t}$. The average torque acting on the wheel during this interval is consequently $\tau=\frac{mR(v-v_{i})}{\Delta t}$.

Hence the angular impulse equals $mr(v-v_{i})$, which can be set equal to the change in angular momentum $\Delta L$,

$mR(v-v_{i}) = I\Delta{\omega} = \frac{I}{R}\Delta{v}$. This yields the linear recurrence relation

$v_{i+1} = v_{i} + \frac{mR^{2}}{I}(v-v_{i})$

which may then be solved by trialling $v_{i} = A\lambda^{i}$ and finding the general solution. If I have made any errors in the above please let me know!

Comment: This is correct.I will accept the answer but do you know from where this sum is taken maybe in the excercises of some classic book or something?

Comment: @AnasuaDogra Sorry, I'm don't know the source of the problem!